# how to pin/stick a box2d body to the ground

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

How can I pin or stick a box2d body (circle or polygon shape) to the ground (body). Sorry if this sounds quite simple, I've not been able to find anything relevant on this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use that body as a static body ..! And it wont move anywhere ..!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also create a weld joint between the body and the ground.